# Как присвоить значение переменной из callback?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

У меня есть callback (это стороннее api), который возвращает мне мой `uid`.

```
VK.api('users.get', {fields: 'photo_max_orig'}, function (response) {
});
```

Сначала я думала, что сделаю вот как:

```
$scope.getUID = function (uid) {
  var q = $q.defer();
  VK.api('users.get', {fields: 'photo_max_orig'}, function (response) {
  if (responce) {
    q.resolve(response['response'][0]['uid']);
  }
  else {
    q.reject(0);
  }
  });
  return q.promise;
}
```

потом создам переменную `$scope.uid = 0`

сделаю так:

```
$scope.promise = $scope.getUID($scope.uid);
$scope.promise.then(
  function(v) {$scope.uid = v},
  function(err) {$scope.uid = err} 
)
```

и у меня всегда будет в `$scope.uid` текущее значение `uid`. Но не работает! Более того, я из функции `VK.api('users.get' ...)` Не могу вызвать никакого callback'a (`$http.post` и всё такое - не работает - пишет ошибку

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token v).

я, конечно, могу оформить функцию `$scope.getUID` callback'ом, но я не хочу постоянно дергать `VK.api('users.get' ...)`. Идеально было б какой-нибудь `promise`. 
Как это сделать? 
Всем спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SyntaxError` - это твоя ошибка. Синтаксическая ошибка - ошибка парсинга скрипта (не выполнения). Найди ту строчку, на которой она возникает и попробуй исправить. Если не получится, приведи соответствующий кусок кода в вопросе.

То, что ты привёл сейчас, синтаксических ошибок не содержит. Более того, я не вижу причин, по которым это не должно работать.

Comment: да я понимаю, но мне нечего больше добавить - я всё уже написала.

Comment: строка, которая генерирует ошибку, я знаю - это - $http.post('main.php', { uid: uid } ).success(function (data) {        
      }); }

Comment: @КаришА, просматривайте внимательно количество скобочек, кавычек, запятых...

Comment: такая ошибка вылетает, когда что-то на стороне сервера неправильно работает.

Comment: @КаришА, проверь, что не пересылаешь json c contet-type'ом javascript'а - jQuery может делать eval.

Comment: @КаришА, хотя я что-то не в тему сказал про json...

Comment: Там не обязательно должна быть ошибка в пересылаемых или отправляемых данных. Просто ошибка на стороне сервере. Я уже разобралась, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Обработчики сторонних событий вызываются вне области видимости AngularJS. Для изменений переменных AngularJS внутри этих обработчиков необходимо вызывать [$scope.$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

```
VK.api('users.get', {fields: 'photo_max_orig'}, function (response) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.uid = response['response'][0]['uid'];
    });
});
```

Comment: Во-первых, не в тему. А во-вторых, разве $q сам этого не делает в её варианте?